# Does CVE always has a fixed patch?

Tags: cve

I'm not sure if there is always a patch to the corresponding CVE ?

And what if `patch_a` doesn't fix the CVE properly and then here comes `patch_b`, so there are two patches to fix one certain CVE. In this case will the CVE reference updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a correct answer we have to check the CVE publication processes,

To begin, the person who find a vulnerability have to tell it to the editor of the impacted product.
After that, the editor have a period to provide a patch.
After this period the vulnerability is published.

Usually the editor have already create a patch and the website who publish the CVE give a link to the patch.
But sometime, after the period there's no patch. Sometime the editor made the decision not to provide a patch. many reason for that :

- The impacted product are not supported ;
- The editor did not have enough time to provide a patch.
  So it is therefore possible not to find a patch for a CVE.

For the second question,
usually, when a patch does not fix properly a vulnerability a second CVE ID are created with a new patch.

Comment: This is wrong. Source1: cve.org "CVE® Program Mission
Identify, define, and catalog publicly disclosed cybersecurity vulnerabilities." Source2: I was a CVE board member and resigned (https://www.cve.org/ProgramOrganization/Board). CVE's are simply public vulnerabilities. Whether or not they have a patch has no bearing at all on the assignment of a CVE.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer:

A CVE identifies a vulnerability or exposure, to quote the cve.org website: "CVE® Program Mission Identify, define, and catalog publicly disclosed cybersecurity vulnerabilities"

If a CVE is assigned, and a patch is issued that claims to fix the CVE, but fails to fix it, or incompletely fixes it, or creates a new vulnerability, well, you win a new CVE. Examples would be easily found by searching for "NOTE: this issue exists because of an incomplete fix for CVE" e.g. https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=because+of+an+incomplete+fix+for